# Can't use internet through usb tethering or wifi in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking

This is the output of `ifconfig -a` command:

```
ifconfig -a
enp0s20f0u2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:92:f8:ea:5f:b5  
          inet addr:192.168.42.80  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4b19:efed:e6a2:c870/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:480 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1547 (1.5 KB)  TX bytes:63021 (63.0 KB)

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:5a:0f:c0:1c:1a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1438 (1.4 KB)  TX bytes:1438 (1.4 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:14:01:17:3a:b9  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: What does `ip route` show?

Comment: what happens when you ping a site ping www.google.com

Comment: Output of ip route command : default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s20f0u2 proto static metric 100 169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20f0u2 scope link metric 1000 192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20f0u2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.80 metric 100

Comment: Nothing happens when I ping any site, the loading circle keeps on rotating in anticlockwise direction.